# Devise is sending e-mails with blank bodies when I override it's mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to override Devise's default mailer to implement some custom functionality. Devise is sending the e-mails, but with blank bodies.
I stripped my custom Mailer of all it's functionality and made it as bare bone as possible, but to no avail.
Here is my code.

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer = DeviseMailer

# app/mailers/devise_mailer.rb
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class you wrote expects its views to be at app/views/devise_mailer/ . If you want to use the devise bodies, generate them or add them the view path.

Comment: I already had them generated, but left them in the default location. apps/views/devise/mailer. On a side note, is the location of the views determined by the class name / namespace, or by the location of the file in which the class is defined?

Comment: yes, it is. its the same as photos_controller expects the related files at app/views/photos/ . Rails is more about convention over configuration